# C# loops not looping an if statement

Tags: c#, loops

I have an if statement within a loop, using `Debug.Write()` I've determined that for the first iteration of the loop everything works as expected, but on subsequent iterations the if block is ignored, but everything else within the loop still executes. I've tried a few variations but so far none of them have worked.

Originally I had:

```
Private int Loop()
{
    int a = 50000;
    int n = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < arrayListFromElsewhere.Count(); n++)
    {
        if ((int)arrayListFromElsewhere[n] < a)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("if loop: " + n);
            a = n;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("N: " + n);
    }
}
```

Which would print:

```
if loop: 0
N: 0
N: 1
N: 2
etc...
```

I've verified that the ArrayList only ever contains integers, replaced the for with a while and tried moving the if into a separate function which is called inside the for/while but nothing has worked so far. So what super obvious thing have I overlooked?

Comment: Your example won't compile as provided; you're defining the variable `n` twice.

Comment: If you don't enter the 'if' block in the second iteration, it's probably because the condition '(int)arrayListFromElsewhere[n] < a' is not met. Can you also trace the value of '(int)arrayListFromElsewhere[n]' to check that?

Answer (score 8):

After the first iteration of the loop, you've set `a` to `n`. From then on, you'll only go into the `if` statement if the value in the `ArrayList` is negative. *Are* any of the values negative? (A short but complete example of the failure would really have helped, by the way - as well as some explanation of what you're *trying* to do.)

(As an aside, why are you still using non-generic collections? 2004 is calling - it wants its code back!)

Answer (score 2):

the first time though the loop a = n while n is zero so when the if is evaluated the second time n =1 a = 0 arrayListFromElsewhere[n] = something > 0

Answer (score 1):

On your first iteration `a` becomes 0 (the value of `n` on your first run).

After that the if statement `if ((int)arrayListFromElsewhere[n] < a)` is always false.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the `if block` will be ignored based on the condition as you specified. Since in the first if block, you have set `a = n`. in that case `a will be 0`. So, subsequent if block will be false and will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have positive numbers in the array, after the first iteration a will be 0 (first n in the if is 0) and it will not enter the if any more.

Also, you have n declared twice.